# Programmers Stack Exchange swag for top users

Tags: discussion

As a thank you for *being awesome*, if you are on page 1 or page 2 of …

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=all

… we'll be sending you a little care package shortly:

- Programmers Stack Exchange t-shirt in your size
- Programmers Stack Exchange die-cut, vinyl stickers
- [Stack Exchange sharpie](http://shop.stackexchange.com/collections/frontpage/products/stack-exchange-sharpies)
- [Stack Exchange pen](http://shop.stackexchange.com/products/stack-exchange-pens)
- [Stack Exchange stickers](http://shop.stackexchange.com/products/stack-exchange-network-stickers)

You can expect to get an email soon with details on how to confirm and provide your mailing address and size preferences.

### The t-shirt

[image: programmers.stackexchange.com t-shirt]

### The sticker

[image: programmers.stackexchange.com sticker]

The rest of the items you can view in the [Stack Exchange store](http://shop.stackexchange.com) — direct links to [sharpie](http://shop.stackexchange.com/collections/frontpage/products/stack-exchange-sharpies), [pens](http://shop.stackexchange.com/products/stack-exchange-pens), [stickers](http://shop.stackexchange.com/products/stack-exchange-network-stickers).

Congratulations!

<sub>(for anyone else who wants this swag, but isn't on page 1 or page 2 of the all time top users -- the limited edition t-shirts and stickers will be available for purchase from the store soon as well)</sub>

Comment: That's mighty kind of you folks!

Comment: Thanks P.SE team!

Comment: Co-sign on the thank you! :) Greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thanks a lot :)

Comment: You guys rock!.

Comment: I feel special :) Thank you.

Comment: Great initiative :)  I'm concerned, however, that I won't be able to fit in an XXL.  Would even larger sizes be an option?

Comment: @Thor: AFAIK, XXL should be 26W, 32L (in inches).

Comment: Note, I'm 199 cm with broad shoulders - just to clarify where the additional X'es need to go :)

Comment: Awesome!! Thanks! See? Who says you shouldn't check your e-mail before starting to work? Made my day.

Comment: woot! woot! woot!

Comment: Even though sadly I'm only middle of page 4, this is a nice move!

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen: why you don't want us to see all your muscles?

Comment: @Pierre, eh, you forget our line of work ;-)

Comment: @Thorbjoern: We call it "Molson Muscle" where I'm from :). http://www.molsoncoorscanada.com/en/Index.aspx)

Comment: Thanks guys :) Can't wait to hit on girls with my new t-shirt :D

Comment: @SnOrfus,you don't NEED to have a beer belly just because you are a programmer ;-)

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen: if you don't wear glasses, that's the only way to be credible ;)

Comment: @Pierre, I wear glasses, you don't.  Conclusion?

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen: you are probably much more credible than me ;) Do you wear geek t-shirts?

Comment: @Pierre, infrequently.  Danish culture is different in that regard.  I have, however, seriously considered http://www.errorwear.com/shirt-pacman.php.

Comment: @back2dos, perhaps the "home improvement" SE swag will have a higher appeal?

Comment: Huh, I had no idea I had so much rep on here... Thanks guys! :)

Comment: Can anyone define "Shortly"? I got the email asking for a shirt size, filled out the form, but no goodies :-(. Now that we're having a postal strike I presume I'll see nothing till it ends, but is it right to assume it was sent before our strike started?

Comment: @kate http://sixtoeightweeks.com

Comment: @Jeff: I supposed I did ask for that. But if it's a genuine estimate, I'm happy, because it means it's not yet on its way and the postal strike will be over by the time it's shipped. As opposed to "we sent them all the next day and your must have got lost." Which would be sad.

Comment: @KateGregory I imagine the shipping time depends on our postal system getting back on its feet sometime soon, too.

Comment: Nive! Unfortunately, I've just noticed that the domain ammoq.com is no longer mine (probably forgot to renew it), so my email adress has changed; see my profile. I'd love to get some swag!

Comment: Don't suppose there'll be a notification when they're sent out?

Comment: Got mine yesterday! Love the shirt, even if I did get made fun of for wearing such a geeky shirt ;)

Comment: Nuts page 5, I would have been happy with a free sticker.

Comment: so, uhm, was that "six to eight weeks" per person... or until they were all sent out. Some people seem to have gotten their swag multiple 6-8 weeks ago.

Comment: @SnOrfus you definitely should have gotten it by now.. email the address on the bottom of every page

Answer (score 8):

Programmers.SE swag just arrived yesterday (Gaming.SE's swag too, but they aren't as cool):

[image: Swag]

Comment: upvote for the pic ... i am out of town this week and am told my package has arrived at home. This way I get to see it.

Answer (score 5):

Shirts are progressing!

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Pens... Pens are great.

[image: shog swag shot]

Answer (score 3):

Is it possible to find out tracking numbers on parcels sent out? Some folks in London (ChrisF) have received their swag, but as yet I haven't. I'm wondering how I can find out where the parcel might be...

Comment: I'm not in London but you raise a valid point.

Comment: I think mine got lost in the mail or something. I've had no sign of swag in my inbox. :/

Answer (score 3):

Here's my action shot on vacation at [Boracay](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boracay). As you can tell, I'm not fond of direct sun:

[image]

Directly in front of me is my daughter. Huge waves and sandy winds tend to creep up there, which is the noise you see on the front of the lens.

Thanks for sending this out :)

Comment: +1 because you're in Boracay, Philippines. :)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is the right place to put this, but I've yet to receive my swag. I filled in the form (although I wasn't sure about my account number) and waited. Any news?

Comment: 6-8 weeks.. we're still working on it!

Comment: Just to say that I returned home to the UK from holiday today and found my package waiting for me. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Got it too! Now I have to figure out where I will use the stickers ;)

Comment: Oooo.... I expected the European stuff to take a bit longer to get here <goes back to staring at the letterbox waiting for loot>

Comment: @Jon Hopkins: Belgium, as the center of europe, is a huge hub. I think it's why it took so little time. Tell me when you receive it in Scotland ;)

Comment: Good point. It will probably hit London pretty quickly and then take as long to travel the last 400 miles as it did to get across the Atlantic.

Comment: I wear the P.SE t-shirt today, and I noticed the size (in height) is almost 5cm greater that normal t-shirts (including the ones I buy when I travel in US). So nobody can see my ass anymore. I prefer standard sizes.

Comment: Have you tried a very very hot wash to shrink it? ;-) I still don't have mine...

Comment: @Jon Hopkins: I have a better solution, I'll put it in the trouser ;)

Answer (score 0):

Mine finally arrived this morning.

Interestingly the date on the letter was the 5th July the same as the Gaming swag which arrived last week.

I blame the UK Post Office.

Comment: I think the UK Post Office must be rather broken, if London users (me) haven't yet received their swag. Sad!